# read words from line in C++

Tags: c++, string, file-io

I was wondering if there was a way to read all of the "words" from a line of text.

the line will look like this: R,4567890,Dwyer,Barb,CSCE 423,CSCE 486

Is there a way to use the comma as a delimiter to parse this line into an array or something?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474790/how-to-read-write-into-from-text-file-with-comma-separated-values/1474819

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, use `std::getline` and stringstreams.

```
std::string str = "R,4567890,Dwyer,Barb,CSCE 423,CSCE 486";

std::istringstream iss(str);
std::vector<std::string> words;

while (std::getline(iss, str, ','))
  words.push_back(str);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I implemented  something similar but without vectors.

Answer (score 0):

```
//#include sstream with angular braces in header files 

std::string str = "R,4567890,Dwyer,Barb,CSCE 423,CSCE 486";

std::istringstream iss(str,istringstream:in);

vector<std::string> words;

while (std::getline(iss, str, ','))
  words.push_back(str);
```