# Reading from text files C++

Tags: c++

I have a text file containing three columns of numbers; one column each for the `x,y,z` coordinates of a bunch of points. All numbers are between `0` and `1`.

I have created the following structure:

```
typedef struct 
{
    double xcd, ycd, zcd;
} point;
```

I want to create a size-N array of structures of type `point`. Then I want to scan the text file line by line and for the `n`th particle, I want to put in the three numbers on the `n`th line into the respective `xcd`, `ycd` and `zcd` positions.

Tell me if there is some efficeint way of going about this.

Comment: There are so many questions for stuff like this.

Comment: `typedef struct`? coming from C?

Comment: A very quick search shows up this pretty good match -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474790/how-to-read-write-into-from-text-file-with-comma-separated-values

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply do it like has been shown five million billion kajillion times before, using `ifstream`, `vector` and various other accouterments.

```
ifstream infile("myfile.txt");

// check if file opened successfully
if (!infile) {
    cerr << "failure, can't open file" << endl;
    cin.get();
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

// the container in which we will store all the points
vector<point> points;

// a temporary point to hold the three coords in while we read them all
point tmp;

// read in three doubles from infile into the three coords in tmp
while (infile >> tmp.xcd && infile >> tmp.ycd && infile >> tmp.zcd)
    // add a copy of tmp to points
    points.push_back(tmp);
```

This will read in three doubles and put them in a `point` then put a copy of that `point` in `points`. However, if the number of numbers in the file modulus 3 is not 0, it will stop and not add the incomplete point to `points`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `std::fstream`.

If you're sure that the file is correct:

```
struct Point { 
    double xcd, ycd, zcd;
};
// btw this is how you should declare a structure in C++,
// the way you shown is rather characteristic to C and only used there

Point tab[N];

void foo() {
    std::ifstream f("file.txt");
    for (int i=0; i<N; ++i) {
        f >> tab[i].xcd >> tab[i].ycd >> tab[i].zcd;
    }    
}
```

If you're not sure that the file will exist and contain exactly this number of particles, you should check for `f.fail()` after each a read attempt.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using the standard generic algorithms to writing my own loops:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>

typedef struct 
{
  double xcd, ycd, zcd;
} point;

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&is, point& pt)
{
  return is >> pt.xcd >> pt.ycd >> pt.zcd;
}

int main(int ac, char **av) {
  std::ifstream f("file.txt");

  std::vector<point> v;
  std::copy(
    std::istream_iterator<point>(f),
    std::istream_iterator<point>(),
    std::back_inserter(v));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another design is to overload the stream extraction operator in your point structure:

```
struct Point
{
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;

    friend istream& operator>>(istream& inp, Point& p);
}

istream& operator>>(istream& inp, Point& p)
{
    inp >> x;
    inp >> y;
    inp >> z;
    inp.ignore(100000, '\n');
    return inp;
}
```

Usage:

```
ifstream myfile("data.txt");
Point p;
vector<Point> point_container;
while (myfile >> p)
{
    point_container.push_back(p);
}
```