# Read from text file and assign to separate variable name

Tags: c++

**My text file is like:**

> mr,John Abrahm,USA,30,M
>   Mr,Harry,UK,40,M
>   Mr,Jack,USA,50,M

**I want to do like:**

```
title=mr  
name=John Abrahm  
country=USA  
age=30  
gender=M
```

So far my code is like:

```
ifstream inputFile("text.txt");
string line;
while (getline(inputFile, line))
{
    istringstream ss(line);

    string title;
    string name;
    string country;
    char gender;

    ss >> title>>nam>>age>>country>>gender;
    cout <<gender<< endl;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/).

A sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="mr,John Abrahm,USA,30,M";
  char * pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str," ,");
  while (pch != NULL)
 {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ,");
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Returns:

```
Splitting string mr,JOhn Abrahm,USA,30,M into tokens:

mr

John Abrahm

USA

30

M
```

Instead of printing the strings you could assign them to variables. You might wanna look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234678/using-getline-with-csv).

**EDIT :** For several rows, say you wanna extract all the 5 entries in each row in 5 different arrays. You first do something like:

```
pch1 = strtok (str," \n");
```

This gives you one particular row which you can further divide with

```
pch = strtok (pch1," ,");
```

This would obviously be possible only with a nested loop.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But, i am using c++ and my file contains many rows (say 100).

Comment: @aatanka I don't see why that's a problem. `strtok` is available  in c++. You only require basic manipulation to extend my answer for several rows. Please see my edit.