# How to copy words from a file spearated by semicolon (;) into an array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, file, copy

This is my first question on StackOverflow and I would really appreciate any help I can get.

I have a file with a German word and its English translation separated by a semicolon in each line.

It looks something like this:

```
Hund;dog
Katze;cat
Pferd;horse
Esel;donkey
Fisch;fish
Vogel;bird
```

I have created the following structure:

```
struct Entry

{
    string english = "empty";
    string german = "empty" ;
};
```

What am trying to do is to create a function that would copy the first word of each line to the string `german` and then skip the semicolon and copy the second word in the line to the string `english` and this should be done line by line into an array of the variable type `Entry`.

This the function I created - of course it's missing a few lines that would do the actual copying. :)

```
void importFile(string fname, Entry db[])
{
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open(fname);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could read the file using a `CSV` reader (search this site for examples).  But for such a simple format you can just read each line with `getline` into a `std::string`, search for the semi-colon, and then get substrings via the `std::string` member function `substr`.

Comment: i think that you should search in google first since it's a question which was answered many times already. for example here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/read-file-line-by-line and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c or that one
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474790/how-to-read-write-into-from-text-file-with-comma-separated-values with that links u can easily create this code:
edit: nvm. u have an answer in another post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a combination of `string.find()` and `string.substr()` you can split a string by a delimiter. With `getline` you can read line by line of the file. Then you need to create new structs and add them to the array. Hereby the main part of the code, do a bit of googling to arrays and you can figure out the rest yourself.

```
  string line;
  string english, german;
  int delimiterpos;
  Entry mEntry;
  ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( getline (myfile,line) )
    {
      //line now consists of the german;english
      delimiterpos = line.find(";");
      german = line.substr(0,delimiterpos);
      english = line.substr(delimiterpos+1,line.size());
       //create a new struct and add it to array.
        mEntry = new Entry();
        mEntry.german= german;
        mEntry.english = english;
        // add to some array here
    }
    myfile.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file";
```

Comment: You should probably check that `delimiterpos != std::string::npos` after find.