# C++ Read characters, integers and doubles with dividing lines from text file into 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, multidimensional-array, vector

```
Bulbasaur|Grass| |2|16|45|65|65|45|0.059
Ivysaur|Grass|Poison|3|32|60|80|80|60|0.059
Venusaur|Grass|Poison| | |80|100|100|80|0.059
Torchic|Fire| |23|16|45|70|50|45|0.045
Combusken|Fire|Fighting|24|36|60|85|60|55|0.045
Blaziken|Fire|Fighting| | |80|110|70|80|0.045
```

These are some data in my text file, which stores Pokemon's name, type 1, type 2, index number of evolved Pokemon from the list, and stats, with character `"|"` as dividing lines, how do I read all hundreds of similar data into a 2D array? Or any other form of array which gives better result?

These are my C++ codes, and the result are totally failure.

```
ifstream inFile;
inFile.open("PokemonBaseStats.txt");
if (inFile.fail())
{
    cerr << "Could not find file" << endl;
}

vector<string> code;
string S;

while (inFile >> S) {
    code.push_back(S);

    inFile >> name >> type1 >> type2 >> evolveTo >> evolveLevel >> hp >> atk >> def >> spd >> catchRate;
    cout << name << type1 << type2 << evolveTo << evolveLevel << hp << atk << def << spd << catchRate;
}
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
```

The output is:-

[image: output]

Comment: What have you tried until now ? Have you checked documentation for `find_first_of` and `find_first_not_of` ?

Comment: Does this help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302996/changing-the-delimiter-for-cin-c

Comment: I would throw this venture better...

Comment: @RandomGuy, i updated the post

Comment: @SergeRoussak, yea, so i ask whether it have a better solutions or not

Comment: @DerrickLaw, no, I doesn't mean a programming.

Comment: @DerrickLaw: Please have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474790/how-to-read-write-into-from-text-file-with-comma-separated-values)
Instead of commas use '|' as the separator.

Comment: Kinda irrelevant to your question, but unless you want to process data further with heavy load in C++, try some scripting language, see [Rule of least power on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_least_power)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a piece of code to do that but I'm not sure if it is exactly what you wanted:

```
        struct Pokemon
        {
        public:
            std::string Name;
            std::string Type1;
            std::string Type2;
            int IdxVector[6];
            float Stat;
        };

        int main(int argc, char *argv[])
        {
            std::string TxtLine;
            int count;
            std::ifstream F("./TextFile.txt");

            std::list<Pokemon> PList;

            while(std::getline(F,TxtLine))
            {
                Pokemon P;

                int idx=TxtLine.find_first_of('|');
                std::string Element=TxtLine.substr(0,idx);
                P.Name=Element;
                TxtLine.erase(0,idx+1);


                idx=TxtLine.find_first_of('|');
                Element=TxtLine.substr(0,idx);              
                P.Type1=Element;
                TxtLine.erase(0,idx+1);

                idx=TxtLine.find_first_of('|');
                Element=TxtLine.substr(0,idx);              
                P.Type2=Element;
                TxtLine.erase(0,idx+1);

                for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
                {
                    idx=TxtLine.find_first_of('|');
                    Element=TxtLine.substr(0,idx);              
                    P.IdxVector[i]=atoi(Element.c_str());
                    if(Element.compare(" ")==0)
                        P.IdxVector[i]=-1;
                    TxtLine.erase(0,idx+1);
                }
                P.Stat=atof(TxtLine.c_str());
                PList.push_back(P);
            }


            return 0;

        }
```