# Reading list of arrays from input file

Tags: c++, arrays, input

I'm trying to read a list of arrays from an input file, do something with it, then print the results.  I noticed that I was incorrectly reading the arrays, but I couldn't figure out what I was doing wrong.  The problem appears to be that random numbers from previous arrays get added to the end of the subsequent arrays.

To test my code, I added a few lines to make it print out the original arrays that the code read, and it clearly shows that the arrays are no longer the same. I included an example of the original array and my output at the end.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is the part in my code that reads the arrays from the input file:

```
int a[50]={0};
ifstream inputFile;
string s;
stringstream ss;
string outputfile = "out.txt";
...
int n;
char c;
inputFile.open("in.txt");
while(getline(inputFile, line)){
    int stringSize = line.length();
    line = line.substr(1, stringSize - 2);

    istringstream input(line);
    string number;
    vector<int> ints;
    while(getline(input, number, ',')){
        istringstream iss(number);
        int i;
        iss >> i;
        ints.push_back(i);
    }
    copy(ints.begin(), ints.end(), array);
    int size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
    a1(array, size, outputfile);
}
inputFile.close();
```

a1() is the function where I do things with the arrays I read, but that's also where I included the print function for testing.

This is the print part:

```
ofstream output;
output.open(filename.c_str(), ios::out | ios::app);
output << "Original array: ";
for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
    output << a[x];
    if (x != size-1) output << ", ";
}
```

This is what the in.txt looks like:

```
[1, 2, 4, -1, 4, -10, 4, -19, 18, -1, -3, -4, 11, 3, -20, 19, -33, 50, 66, -22, -4, -55, 91, 100, -102, 9, 10, 19, -10, 10, 11, 11, -10, -18, 50, 90]
[12, 12, 14, -88, -1, 45, 6, 8, -33, 2, 8, -9, -33, -8, -23, -77, -89, 1, 9, 10, 92, 87]
[565, 78, 33, 9, 10, 84, 71, -4, -22, -55, -10, 76, -9, -9, -11, 76, 89, 11, 10, -33, 9]
[2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
[2]
[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -100, -10, -10, 100, 100, 100, 100, -100, 100, 10, -10, -1]
[12, 23, 44, -17, 12, 14, -88, -1, 45, 6, 8, -33, 2, 8, -9, -33, -8, -23, -77, -89, 1, 9, 13, -25, 10, 92, 57, 99, -22]
```

This is what my out.txt looks like right now:

```
1, 2, 4, -1, 4, -10, 4, -19, 18, -1, -3, -4, 11, 3, -20, 19, -33, 50, 66, -22, -4, -55, 91, 100, -102, 9, 10, 19, -10, 10, 11, 11, -10, -18, 50, 90, 0
12, 12, 14, -88, -1, 45, 6, 8, -33, 2, 8, -9, -33, -8, -23, -77, -89, 1, 9, 10, 92, 87, 91
565, 78, 33, 9, 10, 84, 71, -4, -22, -55, -10, 76, -9, -9, -11, 76, 89, 11, 10, -33, 9, 87
2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 11
2, 3
-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -100, -10, -10, 100, 100, 100, 100, -100, 100, 10, -10, -1, 3
12, 23, 44, -17, 12, 14, -88, -1, 45, 6, 8, -33, 2, 8, -9, -33, -8, -23, -77, -89, 1, 9, 13, -25, 10, 92, 57, 99, -22
```

Comment: You may want to read this: [Why while(!stream.eof()) is considered bad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong). you should also test for stringstream failures... And again, you believe you can achieve what you are trying to do without going deep into the stream buffers

Comment: I suspect the problem is in `a1()`. It's printing one too many elements. If it has a `for()` loop, it should use `i < n`, not `i <= n`.

Comment: I think that you need to remove `int a[50]={0};` from the beginning of the file and move it inside the `while` loop so your array get initialized each time you read a line. Also replace `while (!inputFile.eof())` with `while(getline(inputFile, s))`

Comment: You can crib most of that you need for the reading part from here: [How to read-write into/from text file with comma separated values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474790/how-to-read-write-into-from-text-file-with-comma-separated-values)

Comment: Thank you guys for the comments, I revised the .eof() part and double checked my print function (added to original post now) but it's still giving me the same problem.

Comment: I moved `a[100]={0}` to the inside of the loop and that seemed to have resolved the issue.  I can now use the arrays correctly, but my output always adds a 0 at the end of the array.    I also tried to initiate with `a[100]={}` instead, but that didn't fix the problem.  This is now a minor issue and doesn't affect my code anymore, but is there something else I can do to get rid of the 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved `a[100]={0}` to the inside of the loop, as one of the comments suggested, and that seemed to have resolved the issue.

I can now use the arrays correctly, but my output always adds a 0 at the end of the array. This is now a minor issue and doesn't affect my code anymore.